Difficulties Encountered in Simulating Quantum Purification Circuits for Magic State Distillation
Recently, I've been studying Kitaev's paper on magic state distillation. Referring to Nathan Babcock's presentation, I wrote a program in MATLAB to simulate the purification circuit. Instead of the final syndrome measurement, I directly replaced it with a projection onto the Z-basis positive direction, as I was only interested in the purification effect. However, the simulation results were disappointing. Regardless of the input quantum state (which had undergone a dephasing transformation), the output always tended towards the maximally mixed state. I'm curious to know where the problem might lie. Thank you very much.

